# How do estimate AR drone height

Tags: ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a AR drone parrot and I use the drone package from Brown university, so is it possible to estimate altitude for drone using the available IMU data in navdata messages...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35891/how-do-estimate-ar-drone-height/) by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1610 on 2012-06-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `/ardrone/navdata` message should contains a field for estimated height called `altd` (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/brown-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/experimental/ardrone_brown/msg/Navdata.msg#16)), which I believe is from the ultrasound sensor on the drone.

In general it is difficult to estimate position from an IMU, as you need to dead reckon over the acceleration values to estimate height, and this process accumulates error.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2013-07-21**:
How would you suscribe to this topic in order to work with the values of altd?